# Why does this question appear to have faded?

Tags: support

For the last fourteen hours, one [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28072/12102) appears (at least on my screen) to have faded in the list of question. The phenomenon is durable against reloading, clearing browser, etc.

What does this indicate? Why does this happen? *Is anyone else seeing this?*

(Chrome/Incognito/MacOS)

> [image: Screen Shot of "faded question"]

[image: Screen Shot of "faded question"]  [image: Screen Shot of "faded question"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *possible* that one of the tags on that question is in your "ignored tags" list. I see the same behaviour on Arqade.SE: I hid all questions about Minecraft, because they get *very* tedious, but they still show up in the question list, just faded like that.

I say only "possible" because on other SE sites (Movies, SciFi), questions with ignored tags get hidden from the question list entirely. I don't know why the behaviour seems to vary between different SE sites, but it does seem to.

Comment: It's because your settings on those sites are set to hide ignored tags instead of graying them out.

Answer (score 2):

Bingo!

> [image]

No idea how this happened, there must be a shortcut that I triggered without knowing it.

Thanks all!

Fixed:

> [image]

Comment: Apparently "failure" was not an option.

Comment: @OrganicMarble you've induced me to literally LOL after midnight, further confirming neighbors' suspicion that I'm weird.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen faded questions, only faded downvoted answers. The "pillars" question looks normal on my screen. I have no ignored tags on this site though.

Comment: a virtual acceptance as well!